# Java constructor script

Tags: java, object, constructor, declaration

does anyone know of an existing script to create java objects based on constructor?

I was thinking about writing one but decided to see if one already exists because it seems pretty simple.

Basically a common component of java objects involves writing

1. `public class nameofObject` where the IDE typically takes care of the package statement and the class statement.
2. creating private variables
3. creating the constructor with the same names of those variables passed in
4. making getters and setters
5. deciding to assign the private variables to the local variables within the constructor , ie

   ```
   public nameofObject(String a, String b, String c){
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       this.c = c;
   }
   ```

this process is very predictable (great for a script) and can be tedious (also great for a computer)

That example only has 3 variables, but objects can have 20, or hundreds of variables.

I haven't seen an IDE or a script automatically create an entire object based on its constructor, but that would be very convenient, and I am considering writing a script in python or ant or bash to do this.

But before I reinvent the wheel, have you ever seen one that does this?

Comment: Just a note. Having huge classes with hundreds of variables usually breaks the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Splitting such a class would probably lead to more easily maintainable code.

Comment: yes @DavidPärsson but one example is how the Twitter Tweet jSON object has 20 variables. I can think of some client side application that will split that up, but initially I think one object will have to hold all of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) can help you as long as you create the arguments to the constructor.

New classes (with package definition) can be created using the New class wizard (1).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> can:

- Create field assignments including the private variables, when pressed while cursor is in a constructor argument (2, 5)
- Create setters/getters, when pressed while cursor is in a field (4)

This requires multiple actions/key presses, but is quite fast and convenient, and very flexible.

Comment: this is excellent, an IntelliJ example and an Eclipse example!

Answer (score 2):

Every decent IDE should assist you to a great degree. Examples in IntelliJ IDEA:

## Create a class with constructor

IDE shows a warning that constructor parameters are unused. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: Create fields]

## Choose fields

Which constructor arguments should be converted into fields?

[image: Params]

## Getters and optionally setters

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> anywhere in your class:

[image: Create get/set]

## Select fields to create getters and setters

[image: Choose fields]

IntelliJ can also assist you in writing `toString()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

---

...or consider [scala](/questions/tagged/scala)?

```
case class NameOfObject(var a: String, var b: String, var c: String)
```

Declaration above creates `NameOfObject` class with three fields, getters setters (use `@BeanProperty` to follow POJO conventions), `toString()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()` already implemented. In one line.

Comment: thank you. I personally use Eclipse so I accepted the other one, but I will always be using this as reference because of the many things intelliJ can do better

Comment: @CQM: no problem! I hope it'll be a good reference for future readers as well.